# Button with border / perimeter as loader?

Tags: javascript, button

Putting aside the actual network integration aspect, what is the best css / javascript technique for creating a button whose perimeter / border is the loader, like this image:

[image]

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I don't know where to begin. Clearly a border can't have "length" to increment from 0% to 100% so that's out. An offset background works for one direction. An SVG path seems most likely but I'm not sure what property to increment.

Comment: You will need to use SVG to achieve that. Draw a path that goes around the border of the button, and then set `stroke-dashoffset` based on the percentage to set the "progress" on the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it what are you looking for?

```css
.rect {
  fill:green;
  stroke-width:3;
  stroke:yellow;
  border-radius: 10%;
  stroke-dashoffset: -50px;
  animation: loader-animation 4s linear;
}

@keyframes loader-animation {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0, 400px;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 400px, 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <rect class="rect" x="10" y="10" rx="5" width="100" height="100"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: That's great except I need the yellow animated bit to grow in length until it's a full border. i.e. the 'tail' stays fixed and the front increases around the box until it meets its tail (and is then essentially a regular yellow border on all 4 sides).

Comment: Edited SVG part